# Is there a way to use gatsby image processing for html5 video poster?

Tags: html, html5-video, gatsby, gatsby-image

Hello to anyone that uses gatsbyJS, would there be anyway to use a gatsby image with the blur up or traced view to serve as a video poster?

```
<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I believe `poster` only takes in a url so I am guessing this is not possible but I am curious if I am missing something. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Gatsby Image API does not work on video, but there is a [separate section of the Gatsby docs that deals with video](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-video/)

Comment: Yes thank you I have read through that but they don't address how one might use something like gatsby image for the html5 video component. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve the same, now I'm thinking to make a timeout function. To have a screenshot that shows the blur effect, than will make it disappear and have the video right behind, sounds like a bit of a work though and not 100% sure will end up right.